# XHR Post aborted in Firefox > 44, Safari and IE, but always Works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a piece of Javascript fully tested and working in many different environments. In this new environment I'm currently facing, this script does not work even using the same browsers.

The problem is the following: this script does and XHR Post to a certain URL (in the same domain) but in Firefox 46 (it DOES work in firefox 43 and 44) and Safari I see in the network monitor "Aborted". In IE randomly works, otherwise remains in pending. **It always works in Chrome**.

Trying to debug the problem I used Fiddler, but Fiddler seems to solve the problem with all the browsers. 
The website is in HTTPS, but I don't think it's an HTTPS related problem because I can directly access to the resource and I can successfully do the same POST with CURL.
It also seems to be a Client Side problem because with Whireshark I can't even see the begin of the request. It seems like the browser drops the XHR POST even before starting it.

What can be the root of this problem? What changed between firefox 44 and 46 regarding the handling of HTTP POST request?

Thanks in advance.

PS: unfortunately I cannot share the code. Anyway, since it does works in different infrastractures, maybe is not needed.

**UPDATE1:**  I just noticed that if I wait a couple of seconds (around 30) and I do "Edit and resend" from the network monitor, the request is correctly sent. If i try before that windowd time I see the "aborted" error

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Firefox 46: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=3005573

I just upgraded to Firefox 47, and it appears to be solved now.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. You were right about Firefox, in fact I upgraded to 47 too and it was solved. Anyway the problem was still present for IE and Safari. I found as a solution, valid for all browsers, enabling the One Connect feature on the Big-IP F5 load balancer. Unfortunately it wasn't something managed by me and I hadn't access to this kind of configuration to do some tests by myself

I hope this information can be useful to someone else encountering the same problem